# How to generate evenly space for a vector?

Tags: matlab

Generating evenly space can use linspace, but I wonder if I can vectorize it. What I mean is as follow:

Given an input vector, say `[1 2]`, I want to generate a `2X6` matrix such that:

- in the first row, the entries are `[0:0.2:1]`
- the entries for the second row are `[0:0.4:2]`

In general, the input vector may not be known, it can change from `[1 2]` to `[1:3:10]` or other vectors. However, the first column much be a zero vector and the number of columns can be treated to be the known in advanced.

I do not want to write it using a for loop if possible.

Comment: You could create a matrix of unitary `linspace` vectors and then use, either a combination of `repmat` and `.*` or `bsxfun` to multiply each column with each element of your target vector.

Comment: If your input vector is `A = [1, 2]` and `L = linspace(0, A(1), 6)`. Then how about `M = A.'*L`. Is this what you want? For this `A(1)=1`, otherwise, you will have to make some adjustments.

Comment: @ Parag S. Chandakkar Thanks. This is what I want to have.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar This seems to be an answer. Maybe you can write it as an answer as well to do things "correctly"?

Comment: @patrik I have added it as an answer. It handles the case where `A(1) ~= 1`. I am sure its trivial to generalize such that it generates an `m x n` matrix `M`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A = [x, y]`, you can generate the desired `2 x 6` matrix `M` as follows:

```
B = A/A(1);
M = B.'*linspace(0, A(1), 6);
```